# Show totals in telerik grid

Tags: asp.net, razor, model-view-controller, telerik, telerik-grid

I am struggling to show totals of few columns in a footer area of Telerik Grid in a Razor view. But no luck, I am just getting labels e.g. "Total Qty:" with blank value as its column total in footer. Can anybody help me on this?

I have the following code in **OrderData.cshtml**

```
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid<DCS.Web.Models.BOM.ProjectBOMModel>()
                .Name("BOMOrderReport")
                .DataKeys(keys =>
                {
                    keys.Add(x => x.Id);
                })
                .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                {
                    dataBinding.Ajax().Select("BOMOrderList", "Report");
                })
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(x => x.ProjectNo).Width(100);
                    columns.Bound(x => x.LineNo);
                    columns.Bound(x => x.PartNo).Width(100);
                    columns.Bound(x => x.Qty).Aggregate(agg => agg.Sum()).FooterTemplate(@<text> Total Qty: <span>@item.Sum</span> </text>).Width(60).Title("Quantity").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" });
                    columns.Bound(x => x.Description).Width(200).Title("Description");
                    columns.Bound(x => x.RequestDate).Width(90).Title("Request Date");
                    columns.Bound(x => x.BookedAmount).Width(100).Title("Booked Amount");
                })
                    .Scrollable()
                    .Pageable(settings => settings.Total(Model.BOMOrderList.Count).PageSize(Count).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
                    .EnableCustomBinding(true))
```

Answer (score 0):

In telerik grid you can use Footer Aggregate to get the total.

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="btnName" DataField="datafield"  HeaderText="Text" FilterControlWidth="50px" FooterAggregateFormatString="{0:N}" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="5%" DataFormatString="{0:N}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" >
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```